# Angular 2 ngb-datepicker navigateTo

Tags: angular

I am using ngb-datepicker in my application. I want to navigate to a particular month/year when a function is executed in my component class. I know there is method in ngbDatePicker called navigateTo that can called to navigate to particular month/year. But this is done in HTML page as below. Can I call the same method navigateTo in component class? Thank you.

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = 
$event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" 
(click)="dp.navigateTo()">To current month</button>
```

Comment: You are using two way binding right. Then pass your value to model variable. Expected actual format pass value to that variable.Try once may be it's working.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it easily in component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('dp') datepicker: NgbDatepicker;
```

then ,

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.datepicker.navigateTo(..);
 }
```

in template ,

```
 <ngb-datepicker #dp ></ngb-datepicker>
```

note: you need to implement the component using AfterViewInit interface.
and import NgbDatepicker, ViewChild and AfterViewInit to the component.ts

Comment: Why can it only be used on `ngAfterViewInit()` and not on `ngOnInit()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah either you can do it in component.ts or in the template itself,

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="dp.navigateTo({year: 2013, month: 2})">To Feb 2013</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware its possible in template, but how the same could be achieved in component.

Comment: check my example, i made it in component. But you have to declare the date picker in template.