# ng-bootstrap: DatePicker NavigateTo

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Trying to change default date and navigate to it with Datepicker Navigation using the [following code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bnoti); however, I keep getting the issue

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

I tried changing the default values to the same value during the `ngAfterViewInit` but its not pointing to the model on changes and I'm not sure how to handle the current value. I tried to include on the constructor the API `NgbDatepickerNavigateEvent` but didn't seem to resolve. Missing how to plug into this API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change view model in `ngAfterViewInit` causes this error, there are many ways to eliminate error, but I suggest calling in `ngOnInit` like this:

```js
export class NgbdDatepickerBasic implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('dp', { static: true}) datepicker: NgbDatepicker;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.model = { month: 12, year: 2022, day: 12 };
  this.datepicker.navigateTo({ year: 2022, month: 12, day: 12});
 }

}
```

[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bnoti-6a1tuk?file=app/datepicker-basic.ts)

[ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular — What, Why and How To Fix It?](https://medium.com/better-programming/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-in-angular-what-why-and-how-to-fix-it-c6bdc0b22787)

Comment: Thanks @Hsuan Lee I forget why I went with ngAfterViewInit instead of OnInit but I was working on multiple issues and this was the last piece. Again Thanks!

Comment: Ah it was this example that I was following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475438

Comment: Yes, you need to call the `NgbDatepicker` instance's method in `ngAfterViewInit `, but you can not change any view data in `ngAfterViewInit`. So we use `{ static: true}` flag to make it is usable in `ngOnInit`.